# RandomForestClassifier vs ExtraTreesClassifier in scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

Can anyone explain the difference between the RandomForestClassifier and ExtraTreesClassifier in scikit learn.  I've spent a good bit of time reading the paper:

P. Geurts, D. Ernst., and L. Wehenkel, “Extremely randomized trees”, Machine Learning, 63(1), 3-42, 2006

It seems these are the difference for ET:

1) When choosing variables at a split, samples are drawn from the entire training set instead of a bootstrap sample of the training set.

2) Splits are chosen completely at random from the range of values in the sample at each split.

The result from these two things are many more "leaves".

Comment: The reason I'm so interested in the extratreeclassifier is that I am getting much better results with ET on a particular problem.  My feature vector is large >200 variables and the variables are very noisy.  The standard RDF classifier gets lousy results but the ET is getting F1 scores of >90%.  The classes are unbalanced with relatively few positive class samples and many negatives.

Comment: See also this more recent answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175523/difference-between-random-forest-and-extremely-randomized-trees

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes both conclusions are correct, although the Random Forest implementation in scikit-learn makes it possible to enable or disable the bootstrap resampling.

In practice, RFs are often more compact than ETs. ETs are generally cheaper to train from a computational point of view but can grow much bigger. ETs can sometime generalize better than RFs but it's hard to guess when it's the case without trying both first (and tuning `n_estimators`, `max_features` and `min_samples_split` by cross-validated grid search).

Answer (score 26):

ExtraTrees classifier always tests random splits over fraction of features (in contrast to RandomForest, which tests all possible splits over fraction of features)

Comment: I'm amused that this comment is literally the word-for-word answer to a Coursera quiz question

Comment: Yeah @Bob it is. I find this answer very useful that's why I posted here, it help other in understanding difference between extra-tree and random forest.

Comment: also came from the same course. and this answer was helpful!

Comment: yes @skeller88 this is amazing course. You should also look at this https://www.coursera.org/learn/competitive-data-science?specialization=aml

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between random forests and extra trees (usually called extreme random forests) lies in the fact that, instead of computing the locally optimal feature/split combination (for the random forest), for each feature under consideration, a random value is selected for the split (for the extra trees). Here is a good resource to know more about their difference in more detail Random forest vs extra tree.

Comment: I think you meant to paste a link.